# Drawing lines between coordinates in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, pure-function

Variable "l" is a list of coordinates and I am trying to draw a line from each coordinate to the next. But how? Apparently the last line isn't working.

```
f[x_] := x^2
l = Transpose[{Range[0, 20],If[EvenQ[#], 1, -1] & /@Total[IntegerDigits[f[Range[0, 20]]], {2}]}]
Graphics[Line[{#1, #2}] & /@ l]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three possibilities:

```
Graphics[Line[l]]
Graphics[Line[{#[[1]],#[[2]]}]&/@Partition[l,2,1]]
Graphics[Line/@Partition[l,2,1]]
```

They all give

[image]

Comment: Or to take advantage of plot features, `ListLinePlot[l, AspectRatio -> 1/8, Axes -> False, Filling -> Bottom]`